# how to subtract two Solar Hijri column date

Tags: python, pandas, jalali-calendar

I have a data frame like this:

| index | ft | rt |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1401/04/21 13:36:00 | 1401/04/21 13:09:16 |
| 1 | 1401/04/21 14:00:00 | 1401/04/21 13:00:00 |

these column dates are based on "the Solar Hijri calendar".
and when I use

```
type()
```

for values in these columns, it shows me that they are as strings.
how can I subtract these columns ?! (ft - rt)
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [jdatetime](https://pypi.org/project/jdatetime/) package to convert your strings into datetime objects:

```
import jdatetime

df['ft'] = df['ft'].apply(lambda x: jdatetime.datetime.strptime(x, '%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S'), axis=1)
df['rt'] = df['rt'].apply(lambda x: jdatetime.datetime.strptime(x, '%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S'), axis=1)

df['sub'] = df['ft'] - df['rt']
```